# What's the difference between dummy variable and one-hot encoding?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm making features for a machine learning model. I'm confused with dummy variable and one-hot encoding.For a instance,a category variable `'week'` range 1-7.When using one-hot encoding, encode `week = 1` as 1,000,000,`week = 2` is 0,100,000... .But I can also make a dummy variable `'week_v'`,and in this way, I must set a 
`hidden variable` which means base variable,and feature `week_v = 1` is 100,000,`week_v = 2` is 010,000... and 
does not appear `week_v = 7`.So what's the difference between them? I'm using logistic model and then I'll try gbdt.

Comment: No difference actually. One-hot encoding is the thing you do to create dummy variables. Choosing one of them as the base variable is necessary to avoid perfect multicollinearity among variables.

Comment: you might be interested in checking [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224051/99338) out to understand how the degree of freedom changes according to the approach you choose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, there is no difference in the effect of the two approaches (rather *wordings*) on your regression.

In either case, you have to make sure that one of your dummies is left out (i.e. serves as base assumption) to avoid perfect multicollinearity among the set.

For instance, if you want to take the `weekday` of an observation into account, you only use 6 (not 7) dummies assuming the one left out to be the base variable. When using one-hot encoding, your `weekday` variable is present as a categorical value in one single column, effectively having the regression use the first of its values as the base.

Answer (score 4):

Technically 6- a day week is enough to provide a unique mapping for a vocabulary of size 7:

```
 1. Sunday    [0,0,0,0,0,0]
 2. Monday    [1,0,0,0,0,0]
 3. Tuesday   [0,1,0,0,0,0]
 4. Wednesday [0,0,1,0,0,0]
 5. Thursday  [0,0,0,1,0,0]
 6. Friday    [0,0,0,0,1,0]
 7. Saturday  [0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

dummy coding is a more compact representation, it is preferred in statistical models that perform better when the inputs are linearly independent.

Modern machine learning algorithms, though, don’t require their inputs to be linearly independent and use methods such as L1 regularization to prune redundant inputs. The additional degree of freedom allows the framework to transparently handle a missing input in production as all zeros.

```
 1. Sunday    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
 2. Monday    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
 3. Tuesday   [0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
 4. Wednesday [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
 5. Thursday  [0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
 6. Friday    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
 7. Saturday  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

 for missing values : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: This seems to be a word-for-word quote from "Lakshmanan, V., Robinson, S., & Munn, M. (2020). Machine learning design patterns. O'Reilly Media., page 29", please reference the source.